# What is an assembly routine and how to use it in Go?

Tags: go

I am reading a *Go* tutorial ([The Way To Go](http://files.cnblogs.com/files/rojas/thewaytogo.pdf)), and it mentions something about **assembly routine**, can somebody please explain what is that? It also states about *implemented 'outside' Go*, and also *no body*... may I know what is the purpose?

Quote as follow:

> To declarer*[sic]* a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine, you simply give the name and signature, and no body:
>
> `func flushICache(begin, end uintptr) // implemented externally`

I tried to search online, but it seems hard to find any tutorial regarding **assembly routine**, what is that alien? And, what is the meaning of **implemented outside Go**?

Comment: A routine written in assembly.

Comment: Haha, can you elaborate more? I learn Go without much Computer science background... is it something related to assembly language? Sorry, i am newbie... :P

Comment: Yes, It's written in assembly, using a dialect somewhat unique to Go.

Comment: There's about a 99% chance you'll never write an assembly routine. They're only used in specific, rare circumstances - *very* performance-sensitive code where it's worth the effort to write raw assembly (not easy) optimized for each platform you want to support (even less easy).

Comment: Example https://golang.org/src/crypto/md5/md5block_amd64.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) and follow the links there.

To cite it

> Machine code or machine language is a set of instructions executed
>   directly by a computer's central processing unit (CPU). Each
>   instruction performs a very specific task, such as a load, a jump, or
>   an ALU operation on a unit of data in a CPU register or memory.
>
> <…>
>
> All practical programs today are written in higher-level languages or
>   assembly language.

The Go's own reference doc on its support for assembler is [this](https://golang.org/doc/asm).